# Backing an actionscript DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, dataprovider

I am trying to implement the model for a DataGrid. The documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS0ab2a460655f2dc3-427f401412c60d04dca-8000.html#WS0ab2a460655f2dc3-427f401412c60d04dca-7fff

indicates that I need to use an implementation of IList which contains rows. What the docs do not indicate however is what interface I need to use to implement a row class. The examples are all in XML, which suggests static content.

What I need is a row implementation that can receive changes from the underlying model and provide them to the DataGrid, and likewise, receive changes from the DataGrid and provide them to the underlying model.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you cite suggests using an `ArrayList` class as one of the possible implementations of `IList` as a data provider. And the `ArrayList` manual states that the row class is plain `Object`, and all the property change handling and notification is done within `ArrayList` instance using its methods for add, update, delete and set index operations. So, either use this class, or `ArrayCollection`, or write your own `IList` implementation that will handle data update notification process in itself, without referring to row class.

I also think that making row class update its container list is rather pointless, because rows are designed to be just data, without any "sanity", and lists are what actively process that data, including reordering, sorting, filtering and so on. Thus, adding such a functionality to row class overturns this (working) model, thus is not needed.